# Logon failed. Details: 28000:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal report that comes with visual studio 2008, mvc 2. 
i want when user clicks on the link the PDF report is generated.

this is my method to configure crystal report

```
    public ReportClass ConfigureReportClass(string strReportPath, object[] objParameters)
    {
        ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
        try
        {
                rptH = new ReportClass();
                rptH.FileName = strReportPath;
                int Count = 0;
                rptH.Load();
                if (objParameters == null)
                    return rptH;
                foreach (object obj in objParameters)
                {
                    ParameterField param = rptH.ParameterFields[Count++];  // first param 
                    param.AllowCustomValues = true;
                    ParameterDiscreteValue Disparam = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
                    Disparam.Value = obj;
                    param.CurrentValues.Add(Disparam);
                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return rptH;
    }
```

and this one to convert it in to PDF

```
        public System.IO.Stream GetPDFStream(CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass rptClass)
    {
        System.IO.Stream stream = rptClass.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        return stream;
    }
```

and this one is my action method in controller

```
        public FileResult GetComplaintFile(String ComplaintNumber)
    {
        HomeBLLC objHomeBLLC = new HomeBLLC();
        ReportClass rptH = objHomeBLLC .ConfigureReportClass(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Complaint/ComplaintReport.rpt"), new object[] { ComplaintNumber });
        return File( objHomeBLLC.GetPDFStream(rptH),"application/pdf" );
    }
```

i can see preview of my report in design view in visual studio but get the exception at runtime

```
 Logon failed.
```

Details: 28000:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user'.
Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\ComplaintReport {5BDD522D-04DA-48CD-9F43-A9C648F195D9}.rpt:
Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportOptions options)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType formatType)
   at myapp.BLL.Home.HomeBLLC.GetPDFStream(ReportClass rptClass) in F:\myapp\BLL\Home\HomeBLLC.CS:line 1082

at myapp.Controllers.ComplaintController.GetComplaintFile(String ComplaintNumber) in F:\myapp\Controllers\ComplaintController.cs:line 709
   at myapp.Controllers.ComplaintController.Complaint() in F:\myapp\Controllers\ComplaintController.cs:line 76
   at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClassd.b*_a()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

my DSN is correctly configured because other application which is using same DSN is running the Crystal report correctly.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i missed the basic thing, after studying the related questions i came to know that i forgot to give the authentication in my configure crystal report method which is necessary 
my modified Method is as follows

```
    public ReportClass ConfigureReportClass(string strReportPath, object[] objParameters)
    {
        ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
        rptH.FileName = strReportPath;
        int Count = 0;
        rptH.Load();
        rptH.SetDatabaseLogon("myusername", "mypassword");
        try
        {
            if (objParameters == null)
                return rptH;
            foreach (object obj in objParameters)
            {
                ParameterField param = rptH.ParameterFields[Count++];  // first param 
                param.AllowCustomValues = true;
                ParameterDiscreteValue Disparam = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
                Disparam.Value = obj;
                param.CurrentValues.Add(Disparam);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return rptH;
    }
```

the Only thing i added is   **rptH.SetDatabaseLogon("myusername", "mypassword");**  
to my code and its working.
no idea why i have to give the authentication again because i already gave authentication in my DSN. any Suggestions are Welcome.